# Link to View Record from datatable, data gets lost while rendering view page

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a use-case where I have a list of users being displayed using a dataTable.

I have generated Edit and View links against each record.

What I am trying to do is as soon as I click on View link, a separate page should with the details of user.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{profile.goToViewPage(profileVar.profileId)}" value="view" />
```

So the values get correctly passed to Bean.

```
@Named("profile")
@Scope("view")
public class ProfileDTO {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date dob;

    //Getters and Setters

    private void getUser(String selectedProfile) {
        this.setDob(new Date());
        this.setFirstName("Tested from Page First");
        this.setLastName("Test from Page Last");
    }

public String goToViewPage(String selectedProfile) {
        LOG.debug("Goto View Page called for user id : {}", selectedProfile);
        getUser(selectedProfile);
        return "pretty:viewprofile";    //Using prettyfaces
    }
}
```

And the viewPage xhtml is something like:

```
<rich:collapsiblePanel header="Basic Details" switchType="client" expanded="true">
<h:panelGroup styleClass="align-table-center-horizontal" layout='block'>
    <h:column>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%;" columnClasses="right-column half-width,left-column half-width">
            <h:column>
            <h:outputText styleClass="headerText" value="First Name" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:inputText value="#{profile.firstName}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText styleClass="headerText" value="Last Name" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:inputText value="#{profile.lastName}" />
        </h:column>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:column>
</h:panelGroup>
</rich:collapsiblePanel>
```

And the bean that I am using to display list is in session scope.

Problem:
Method gets "goToViewPage" gets called and dummy data is set, but later the constructor is again called and all data is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the issue. It was less of jsf and more of prettyfaces. The issue was resolved, using query parameter and reconstructing the object back for display.

```
<url-mapping id="viewprofile">
    <pattern value="/a" />
    <view-id value="/a/b.jsf" />
    <query-param name="id">#{bean.id}</query-param>
    <action>#{bean.loadViewPageData}</action>
</url-mapping>
```

Using pretty-faces configuration, the action method is set which will get invoked after the request is redirected.